# google-maps distancematrix - departure time

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the Google distancematrix API in combination with departure_time but I'm not getting accurate responses. Not for distances in Europe (Belgium), nor for distances in US (Boston-New York).

I used the same locations starting from Monday morning and with an increased time of 12 hours and the duration is fairly similar (only differences in minutes).

I worked in both regions and know for a fact the traffic jams are lengthy, especially on working days so I don't believe for a second the travel duration would vary only with a couple of minutes.

Please find two responses for the travel Boston-New York below (first response for travel on Friday, second response for travel on Sunday:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Boston, NY 14025, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "5th Ave, New York, NY, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "590 km",
                  "value" : 589831
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "6 hours 9 mins",
                  "value" : 22137
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "6 hours 8 mins",
                  "value" : 22106
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Boston, NY 14025, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "5th Ave, New York, NY, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "590 km",
                  "value" : 589831
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "6 hours 9 mins",
                  "value" : 22137
               },
               "duration_in_traffic" : {
                  "text" : "6 hours 5 mins",
                  "value" : 21916
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data generated by Distance Matrix API are calculated by the Google Maps API. In terms of accuracy, there will always be some slight deviation from it. The more data you provide the API, hopefully it will be more accurate.

If you check the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixRequests), there are other optional parameters that can help you with this. Specifying `traffic_model=pessimistic` return the actual travel time on most days, though occasional days with particularly bad traffic conditions may exceed this value. If you didn't specify this parameter, it will use `best_guess` value.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. 2 remarks however. IMHO, the API seems a kind of bizar since using departure_time should be sufficient to differentiate between a working day and a day on weekend. On a working day, an average travel will obviously take more time and it's a little confusing why one has to opt for a pessimistic/optimistic scenario in addition (my preference would be a neutral/average flavor). Second remark is on the accuracy of the retrieved information. When I use the traffic_model , the duration tends to vary a little more but the information still doesn't seem very reliable to me.